# action=""とは

Tags: php, html

フォームタグの中にある`action=""`とはどういう意味でしょうか？
普段はここにURLやファイル名を入れていたのですが、例で`””`という記載を見つけて・・・。
検索しても見つけられなかったのでよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常は「フォームデータの送り先」を`action=`でURL(またはファイル名)を指定しますが、質問のように空欄になっているものは**自分自身**(=今現在表示しているページ)にデータを送る場合だと思います。

よくあるフォームタグの使い方としては、FORMタグはHTMLページに記載してあり、データの送り先はPHPなどのプログラムに処理させる方法です。
ここでPHP自身にFORMタグを記載してしまえば、自分自身を呼び出して表示を更新することができるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ログイン画面の作成例にでてきて、辻褄も合うので納得です。助かります。